# XSLT - Recursively Working Outwards

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

I understand how to process this doc (below) with XSLT from the outermost *person* element to the innermost. But I was wondering if:

1. If its possible to work from the deepest element out.
2. What that would look like given my example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<container>
  <person name="Larry">
    <person name="Moe">
      <person name="Curly">
        <person name="Shemp">

        </person>
      </person>
    </person>
  </person>
</container>
```

Comment: @Bruno Tyndall I have tested this transformation with .NET 2.0 + XslCompiledTransform. It should work OK with the older XslTransform, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is the most general way of performing "backwards recursion"** that does not depend on this specific problem and can be used in a wide variety of problems.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:call-template name="backwardsRecursion">
        <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="//person"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="backwardsRecursion">
      <xsl:param name="pList"/>

      <xsl:if test="$pList">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$pList[last()]"/>

        <xsl:call-template name="backwardsRecursion">
          <xsl:with-param name="pList" select=
           "$pList[position() &lt; last()]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the originally-provided XML document, produces the wanted result**:

```
Shemp
Curly
Moe
Larry
```

**Do note**, that a generic template named "backwardsRecursion" is called, that really implements the backwards recursion. **This template does not know anything about the nodes it processes, or how they will be processed**.

Thus, this template **can be used in every situation where backwards recursive processing is needed.**

Comment: +1. I'll have to test this strategy in my .NET app tomorrow. I think the .NET XSLT processor should handle all these tags.

Comment: @Bruno Tyndall I have tested this transformation with .NET 2.0 + XslCompiledTransform. It should work OK with the older XslTransform, too.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the parent:: axis for working up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//person[not(person)]"/>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> -&gt; <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::person"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not tested, I may be off-syntax.

It should print Shemp -> Curly -> Moe -> Larry

Comment: Would be worth +1 just for "//person[not(person)]". :-)

Answer (score 1):

**A solution similar to that of teun, but allowing "person" elements to be in not immediate parent-child relationship** is the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//person[not(person)]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person" name="tPerson">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,'&#xA;')"/>

       <xsl:apply-templates select=
          "ancestor::person[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the originally provided XML document, the correct result is produced**:

Shemp

Curly

Moe

Larry

**It is good to know that many problems of this type do not require recursion at all!
This transformation produces exactly the same result and only involves iteration**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:for-each select="//person[not(person)]">
          <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::person | .">
            <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,'&#xA;')"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note the sort** that ensures the reverse order of processing.